# mostrar imagen en una cell (celda) fpdf

Tags: php

saludos amigos tengo un problema estoy haciendo una consulta  y todo bien el problema es como cuadro la imagen dentro de una celda en fpdf ya que se me muestra todo descuadrado, el codigo que implemento es el siguinete:

```
<?php
require('../pdf/fpdf.php');
require('../conexion/conexion.php');
$pdf =& new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'letter'); //para que la hoja sea tipo carta
$pdf->AddPage('P','letter'); //para que la hoja sea tipo carta
$pdf->Image('../cintillo/cintillo.png',10,8,120);
$pdf->Ln(40);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(190, 8, utf8_decode ('Listado General Galerías'), 10,8, 'C');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFillColor(2,157,116);//Fondo verde de celda
$pdf->SetTextColor(3, 3, 3); //Letra color blanco
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 9);
$pdf->Cell(10, 5, utf8_decode ('Cód.'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(60, 5, utf8_decode ('Título'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(100, 5, utf8_decode ('Imagen'), 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM galerias ORDER BY id";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$link);//devuelve la consulta
$i=1;

while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$pdf->Cell(10, 5, $i, 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(60, 5,$row['titulo'], 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(100,5, $pdf->Image('../galerias/'.$row['portada'], $pdf->GetX()+40, $pdf->GetY()+3, 30), 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln();
$i++; 
} 


$pdf->SetY(10);

$pdf->AliasNbPages();


$pdf->Ln(8);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$pdf->Cell(114,8,'',0);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
$pdf->Output('Reporte General Galerias.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

[image: imagen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

has probado de esta manera

```
$pdf->Cell(11,11, $pdf->Image('images/prueba.jpg', $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),11),1);
```

espero te funcione

Comment: gracias me a quedado asi: $pdf->Cell(10, 15, $i, 1,0,'C','R');
$pdf->Cell(100, 15,$row['titulo'], 1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,15, $pdf->Image('../galerias/'.$row['portada'], $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),20),1);
$pdf->Ln();

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdf->Cell(15,15, $pdf->Image("prueba/".$data['imagen'], $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),15,15),1);
```

me funciono a mi

Answer (score 0):

este es el codigo que yo implemente:
$pdf->Cell(27,27, $pdf->Image($imagen, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),0,25),1, 'C');
Lo unico que aun no pude hacerlo es centrarlo

Comment: Vendría bien para el OP y para gente que vea tu respuesta en el futuro que expliques que hace tu código.